# Multiple logger in same class using jboss7 default logging mechanism

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

Basically I need to log two messages in the same class with same logger threshold using jboss7 logging mechanism. Please let me know how this can be done in detail?
I followed the approach you suggested, and created two periodic-rotating-file-handler as below

```
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_DEBUG">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="File111_debug.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_INFO">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="File222_info.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

            <logger category="com.mypackage">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE_DEBUG"/>
                    <handler name="FILE_INFO"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>

        <root-logger>
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>

and in my class, I have declared as below,

package com.mypackage.log

ClassA{
private static final Logger loggerDebug = Logger.getLogger("FILE_DEBUG");
private static final Logger loggerInfo = Logger.getLogger("FILE_INFO");

method1()
{
    loggerDebug.debug("This message should be logged into  DEBUG log file");
        loggerInfo.info("This message should be logged into  INFO log file");
}

}
```

Although though the new logger files got created under the log folder, the above lines are not being printed in the respective log files.

Appreciate if you could help me to check what went wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign handlers to a logger, but all messages logged through that logger will use the handlers specified.

The easiest way to solve this would be to use two different logger categories. Using the `Logger.getLogger(Class<?>)` is just a shortcut for `Logger.getLogger(Class<?>.getName())`. Which means you could do something like:

```java
package com.example;

class ClassA {
    private static final Logger LOGGER1 = Logger.getLogger(ClassA.class.getName() + "1");
    private static final Logger LOGGER2 = Logger.getLogger(ClassB.class.getName() + "2");

    void method1() {
        LOGGER1.info("This message should be logged to a file called File111"); 
        LOGGER2.info("This message should be logged to a file called File222");
    }
}
```

Then configure the logging subsystem like:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    ...
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE1">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} "/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="File111.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE2">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} "/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="File222.log"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>

    <logger category="com.example1">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handlers name="FILE1"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>

    <logger category="com.example2">
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handlers name="FILE2"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    ...
</subsystem>
```

Another option would be to use a filter on the logger category, but that would require knowing some kind of pattern as to what message goes to what handler.

Comment: Thanks a lot James for your immediate response

Comment: I have modified the question as I could not paste the content here.. appreciate your response

Comment: So you want one with DEBUG and higher and one with INFO and higher?

Comment: basically there are existing 'info' and 'debug' level messages that are being logged to a file. But as per the new requirement I need to log few more additional 'info' messages in a key value pair so that only these messages needs to be logged to different file as the log messages logged to this new file will be picked up by some other application for analysis. Please let me know what is the best way to achieve this requirement